# AddType application/x-httpd-php82 .php downloads content instead of executing php - Xampp

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, xampp

I'm using Xampp 8.2.4-0 on Ubuntu 23.10 and want to create `.htaccess` file that will be able to set php version (8.1 or 8.2 etc.)

I'd like this to work

```
AddType application/x-httpd-php82 .php
```

but it causes CORS errors (or - when CORS is added to `.htaccess` - requests download php file content instead of executing it)

Also tried changing `AddType` to `AddHandler` and adding the following to `lampp/apache2/conf/httpd.conf` but to no avail

```
LoadModule php8_module modules/libphp8.so
```

Setting it without php version works but it's not what I need

```
AddType application/x-httpd-php .php
```

Comment: You need to add more information to your question. What php packages are actually installed? Why exactly is the `AddType` directive without version code not "what you need"? What do yo actually mean by "when CORS is added to `.htaccess`"? You appear to try to load php as a module into the http server, which is impossible for _different_ such modules for obvious reasons, so what is your execution strategy for different php versions? Do you have a fastcgi container running? Or plain old cgi?